# Modify a .NET Environment variable from a Webservice in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, environment-variables

I am using the following code in a c sharp file in a .NET Environment:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void SetEnvironmentVariable()
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TNS_ADMIN", "path1", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
    }
```

However the variable is not modified. I even added it in a Global.asax file, but it still does not work.
Any ideas?

Comment: How are you checking to see if it is set? Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environmentvariabletarget?view=net-6.0) that target will write to the registry.

Comment: i.. i have no idea why you want to do this. a public facing service capable of setting environment variable may compromise security of the host system as a whole. then for this very reason, iis application pool have its own set of [constrained environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-environment-variables). it took precedences over system's and only visible for the said application pool.

Comment: I check the TNS_ADMIN using echo %TNS_ADMIN% and this is not modified

Comment: If this is actually doable via a web method in an HTTP call, please, for the sake of security, do not do this.

Comment: If I cannot use a Web Method, how could I change the value of the Environment Variable per each session? The app is using a thin Client that is installed in the user's desktop and a Web Service that runs in IIS